# Solving a stiff system of ordinary differential equations (Initial Value Problem)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

$$
\ddot{x}_1 = f_1(x_1,\dot{x}_1,x_2,\dot{x}_2)
$$
$$
\ddot{x}_2 = f_2(x_1,\dot{x}_1,x_2,\dot{x}_2,x_3,\dot{x}_3)
$$
$$
\ddot{x}_3 = f_3(x_2,\dot{x}_2,x_3,\dot{x}_3,x_4)
$$
$$
\ddot{x}_4 = f_4(x_3,x_4,\dot{x}_4,x_5,\dot{x}_5)
$$
$$
\ddot{x}_5 = f_5(x_4,\dot{x}_4,x_5,\dot{x}_5,x_6)
$$
$$
\ddot{x}_6 = f_6(x_5,x_6)
$$

I've got the above stiff system of 2nd order differential equations and I know all of the initial conditions.  I solve this by converting the system into first order differential equations and then using numerical methods I integrate (I've tried both forward and backward Euler and explicit RK4).  At steady-state everything is fine but one of the constants in $f_4$ and $f_5$ make an abrupt change during the simulation and I'm not sure how deal with it.

I've tried making the step size very small but the system responds wildly with all three methods.  Is my solution procedure incorrect?

Comment: Is this rapid change a static property of the equations or some dynamic property of the numerical solution? // It would make sense to compress the equations to $\ddot {\bf x}=f({\bf x},\dot {\bf x})$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "static property" or "dynamic property".  The rapid change happens a predefined time in the simulation.  I can control when it happens.

Comment: Then you need to add the time parameter to the equations, $\ddot {\bf x}=f(t,{\bf x},\dot {\bf x})$. How do you decide that the observed behavior is a deviation from the exact solution? Is the Lipschitz constant sensibly bounded? Note that you always need $Lh\lesssim 2$ to get stability in these explicit methods.

Comment: This is a model of a physical system that I have experimental data for, so I know how the system is supposed to react.
I am unsure of how to calculate the Lipschitz constant.

Comment: I should also mention that I've tried implicit euler method and it yields the same results as the two explicit methods

Comment: Compute the Jacobi matrix (close to the jump, repeat for several places), exact or per divided differences, and of that some operator norm or the spectral radius. This should give an impression of what the Lipschitz constant should be. It does not need to be very exact, we are just looking for a hint if the observed behavior is to be expected or if there is some error somewhere.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you for taking the time to help me.  I've computed the Matlab norm of the Jacobian throughout my simulation.  It varies from :
5.58863184957x10^11 to 5.58863184949x10^11 ( not much I think)

Comment: This would require very small step sizes, usually $Lh\le2.5$ is necessary for RK4, $L$ being the Lipschitz constant which is an upper bound for the matrix norms. Even smaller for better accuracy. This strongly suggests to use implicit methods that do not have such a stability restriction on the step size.

Comment: Thank you again for the suggestion.  Could you point me in the direction of one such implicit method?